# Cucumber version - 6.9.1 - Couldn't pass blank string in Scenario Outline "Examples"

Tags: cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

After upgraded cucumber version to 6.9.1, blank (empty string) couldn't be passed in Examples.
Passing empty strings used to be possible before

```
  Scenario Outline : Testing datatable with empty string
    When passing "<first>" and "second>" as String parameter
    Then exception should be thrown
     Examples:
      | first  | second |
      | simple |        |
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to use this in `cucumber-java` version `6.9.1` . Just tested it

```
Scenario Outline: example
    Given I log <TestString>
     
      Examples:
        |TestString|
        |"                   " |


 @Given("I log {string}")
        public void logSomething(String teststr )   {
            System.out.println("sample text:"+ teststr+"somethingtoIdentifySpace");
       }
```

Prints this

```
sample text:                   somethingtoIdentifySpace
```